# Custom links on Paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I have implemented will_paginate and I would now like to change the default pages to dates from a ruby variable. How would I go about doing that?

To be a bit more precise: my goal is to have 1 page per date and have all the data that belongs to this date on this page

Snippet from view:

```
  def show
    @waves = @location.infos.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
    gon.watch.infos = @location.infos
    respond_with(@location)
```

Snippet from controller:

```
<table class= "table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th><strong>Day</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Swell Size</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Swell Rating</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Wind Speed</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Temperature</strong></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- <%= will_paginate @waves, previous_label: "Previous day", next_label: "Next day", renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %> -->              
                <%= will_paginate(@waves, :renderer => PaginationListLinkRenderer) %>
                <% @waves.each do |wave| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= Time.at(wave.day.to_i).to_s.chomp("-0800")%></td>
                    <td><%= wave.size_min%>-<%= wave.size_max%><small>ft</small></td>
                    <td><% swell = wave.swell_rating %>
<td><%= wave.wind_speed%><small>mph</small></td>
                    <td><%= wave.temperature%><small>°F</small>   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really paginating `infos` in this case. You're paginating `created_on` attribute for those records.

So:

- make sure you have `created_on` on those records
- grab those records grouped by `created_on`. Raw sql, or a scope will do a job. (scope won't we returning proper objects though)
- When you have an array of `created_on` dates you'll need to create some sort of pagination control to display those. You might be able to use will_paginate for arrays, I think.
- Load your infos scoped on the selected date: `@location.infos.for_date(params[:date])`

Basically, what you want to do requires some elbow grease.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, I have created_on on the records but also a property called day which is a unix timestamp which is the one I want to use. However where do I create the sql query (type what file etc) and the the pagination control. Can you supply some example code please ?